# Retrieve text from page with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to retrieve text from a remote URL and put it in a DIV on my current page. First I'm trying to get the text from a local file first, but it doesn't seem to pull the text. Any suggestions?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>HTML5 with jQuery</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="replace">
        Placeholder
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.get("test.txt", function(data) {
                $("#replace").html(data);
                }
            );
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you opening the parent page in `http://` ? You can't do that in `file://` due to same origin policy.

Comment: Now that you mention it - i believe it's going through file://, I'm getting XAMPP going now to give a better test.

Comment: That was it... Thanks! I'm far too rusty with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) prevents your page from reading in JavaScript a page coming from another origin (roughly domain+port).

A special case is the one of the `file://` protocol : all files opened in this protocol are considered from different origins.

That's why you must use an http server to test your AJAX code.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'text' datatype in your $.get() request.

```
$.get('test.txt', function(data) {
   $("#replace").html(data);
}, 'text');
```

Please note that last argument is the string `text`

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
            url : "test.txt",
            dataType : 'text',
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                // your ops
            }
});
```